# Need to add paste special condition a copy.destination for loop

Tags: excel, for-loop, copy-paste, vba

I have a range of data that is in the same position in every worksheet in a book and will always be in that position. When the macro is run the data should be copied and added to a report sheet. I have that part working but I need to use a paste special:

```
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

as there are formulas in the range. I am unsure where to add the paste special condition in this code, since I'm using `.Copy, Destination`.

```
Option Explicit
Sub CreateTempPSDReport()

    Dim WS As Worksheet, Rept As Worksheet

    Set Rept = Sheets("Temporary PSD Report")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    '--> Loop through each worksheet except the report and
    '--> Copy the set range to the report
    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not WS.Name = "Temporary PSD Report" Then
            WS.Range("A42", "I42").Rows.Copy _
            Destination:=Rept.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > > ```
> > >        I need to use a paste special:
> > >        WS.Range("A42", "I42").Rows.Copy _
> > >        Destination:=Rept.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
> > > ```

In such a case you do not use the above method. You use this

```
WS.Range("A42", "I42").Rows.Copy

Rept.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial _
Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: Fantastic! Will accept this when I'm allowed to, in 7 minutes.. :):)