# Using ranges, how can I make a .COPY DESTINATION paste as VALUES

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have the following code, which works just fine to copy the entire cells to their new destination.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range

Set ws = Sheets("Duplicates")
Set rng = ws.Range("A2")

rng.Copy Destination:=Range("A2:A" & Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
```

1. Is it possible to make that cope a `paste special`.
2. Or do I
   need to split the copy/paste into two lines using a two range
   objects?

EDIT:

Right, we've concluded that you CANNOT have a paste special on the same line as a copy.  What I've also found is that you may not wish to anyway.

If you copy a formula from Record 1 and paste it to all the records as `VALUES`, you will get the formula's value for the first record copied down.

This is not what I wanted.  So you have to copy the formulae down to all the records as a formulae, then copy those formula and paste as values.

---

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range
Set ws = Sheets("Duplicates")
```

Set up first range (single cell with formula) and copy/paste the contents down to the bottom of the spreadsheet based on Col `G`:

```
Set rng = ws.Range("A2")
rng.Copy Destination:=Range("A2:A" & Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
```

Select the freshly pasted formule, from the second row down.  Copy them.  Then paste the contents as values to the same place.

```
Set rng = ws.Range("A3:A" & Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
rng.Copy
rng.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: See a previous answer I wrote here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721781/worksheet-paste-values-save-as-then-return-the-original-file-using-vba/12723462#12723462

Comment: Thank you @mattboy, but that doesn't totally answer my question.  I want to have the single line do a paste special.  Is this possible?

Comment: Not that I know of. If it's possible I'd love to know about it, hopefully someone has an answer!

Comment: Option 1 is not possible. Here's the [MSDN on the copy method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837760.aspx) which only allows 1 parameter. You need to use Option 2 as mattboy linked.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597988/need-to-add-paste-special-condition-a-copy-destination-for-loop

Comment: @aSystemOverload if you found the answer to this you can create an answer to your own question and select it.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you can just assign range values without using copy & paste:

```
Set r1 = Range("D1", "D7")
Set r2 = Range("E1", "E7")

r2.Value = r1.Value ' copies current values from one range to another
```

after this assignment, the r2 range will have values not formulas even if r1 has forumlas.

In your case, perhaps:

```
rng.Value = rng.Value
```

(once you've set rng to the correct size as you've noted)