# Open a file path inside an Excel workbook to then copy and paste back into the workbook where the macro is stored

Tags: excel, vba

The goal is to open a workbook then copy from that workbook to the workbook where the macro is stored.

Workbook A (wbDestination): A multi-worksheet Excel workbook, where the macro will be stored and where the information on Workbook B will be pasted.
The file path of Workbook B is in cell C2 on a worksheet called "Macros" within Workbook A.
I need the source data from Workbook B to be pasted into "Sheet2" on Workbook A.

Workbook B (wbSourceData): A multi-worksheet workbook with the source data on the second worksheet.

```vb
Sub CopyPaste()

    Dim wbSourceData As Workbook
    Dim wbDestination As Workbook
    Dim wsSourceData As Worksheet
    Dim wsDestination As Worksheet
    Dim strFName As String
    
    Set wbDestination = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsDestination = wbDestination.Sheets("Sheet2")
    
    strFName = wbDestination.Worksheets("Macros").Range("C2").Value
    
    Set wbSourceData = Workbooks.Open(strFName)
    Set wsSourceData = wbSourceData.Worksheets(2)
    
    wsSourceData.Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    wsDestination.Select
    Range("A4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
    wbSourceData.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
End Sub
```

I am able to open Workbook B.

When I try to copy the data I get

> Run-time error '1004': Select method of Range class failed

I also want to use the range selection functions `xlToRight` (twice) and `xlDown` on Workbook A because the number of rows of this source data will change monthly and this is the best way to grab the entire range. I will need the source data from Workbook B to be pasted into Workbook A as Paste Values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very nicely set up. I like the care you took with the naming. It's very helpful. But when it came to copy/paste you didn't read the chapter where they said "you need not select anything". Here is an improved version of that part of the code.

```
With wsSourceData
    ' last used cell in row 2 looking from right to left
    Cl = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    ' last used row in column A looking from bottom up
    Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(Rl, Cl))
End With
Rng.Copy Destination:=wsDestination.Range("A4")
```

As you see, the job is to specify a `Range`. Of course, the `Selection` object ***is*** a range. Excel uses it to convey to its back office what the user has clicked on the screen. It isn't very well suited for anything else and therefore is used in place of a range whenever employed. Hence, go straight for the range if it's a range you need.

`xlToRight` looks for the next empty cell **on** the right. `xlToLeft` looks for first used cell **from** the right. Your code jumps over a blank cell to find the end. Same for looking from top down or from the end up. I hope there aren't any more filled cells to the right that you, in fact, want to exclude or from the top down. If so, the variables `Rl` and `Cl` must be found using the code you employed. Setting the range would be done with the same variables set differently.

Here are the declarations I added to the ones you already have.

```
Dim Rng             As Range
Dim Cl              As Long                 ' last used column
Dim Rl              As Long                 ' last used row
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I appreciate it a lot!! So I added those three declarations below the first five I had written. I completely cleared by copy and paste code that I wrote. From the line  wsSourceData.Range("A2").Select  down to  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues  .  I replaced that code with the code you had written. I am not getting any errors, which is good but I am not getting the results I had wanted as the information is not being pasted over to my wsDestination.

Comment: I'd like to clarify I straight up copied and pasted your code. From your notes, I think you are asking me to edit the code a little that you wrote to specify my range. I can tell you the range I will be grabbing will always be from Columns A - N, so Columns 1 - 15. However, the amount of rows will vary every month. It might be worth noting that the source data has column headers that I do NOT want to copy, hence the reason I want the macro to copy starting on the second row.

Comment: On review I find that the Destination range should be properly specified and I changed that line in my answer to read `Rng.Copy Destination:=wsDestination.Range("A4")`. You don't appear to have analyzed the exact error you get. If the choice of destination was the problem the above should cure it. If it's the selection of the source range, add `Debug.Print Rng.Address` below `Set Rng = ` and see what's wrong with it. Having a hint will make the error easy to discover and fix.

Comment: It was the destination that was the error.That fixed it!! I cannot tell you how appreciative I am of you!

Comment: Hey, I know this was a while ago but is there any way you would know how to paste as values. I am running into a little trouble because when the source data is pasted over to the destination the macro is carrying over the format from the source data. Then I have to redo the format on the destination to what it previously was. So my thinking was to somehow alter the macro a little bit so the source data is pasted as values to the destination? Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12821844/using-ranges-how-can-i-make-a-copy-destination-paste-as-values  I think this thread might help

Comment: You could do this with `Rng.Copy: WsDestination.Range("A4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`. Another way would be like this: `WsDestination.Range("A4").Resize(Rng.Rows.Count, Rng.Columns.Count).Value = Rng.Value

Comment: Thanks! Would you have any idea on how to use offset here if I wanted to update this macro. The goal would still be to use the dimensions to grab the last used row but I would want to edit this so I would grab the last used  -3 columns. So basically all of the columns except the last 3 columns on the right side as my range. If the range was columns A-G, I would want to use offset so I am only grabbing columns A-D. I'm toying with using CurrentRegion.Offset(0,3), but it is not working the way I want it to.

Comment: In essence, this is another question but ...I'm no fan of `Offset` because if you know the base and know the offset you can also set the range. Set a range with `Set Rng = Range([First Cell], [Last Cell])`. Last used cell in a row is `Cells([Row], Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)`. Last used column is `Cl = Cells([Row], Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`. 3 last used cells in a row are `Range(Cells([Row], Cl -2), Cells([Row], Cl ))`